# Error 400 on login with ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, iis-10, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I have an application that has been running for 4 years with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` and .NET Core 2.2 . I have a modification to make and I have taken out the old file .ZIP. I had done this project in time with VS 2017. Now I'm with VS 2022.

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="login_section">
        <div class="img-responsive">
            <img src="~/images/Logo.PNG" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <form id="account" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Courriel" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>             
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Connexion</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </section>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}



[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Courriel")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
                var roles = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }               

            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

When I launch the program, I get an error: HTTP ERROR 400

Yet this program has been operating for several years.

I can't put my finger on the bobo. I know it's still in NET Core 2.2, but I'd like to make it work before I migrate it. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You are now switching to DOT NET 6 version on Visual Studio 22. Identity has changed over the time. You need to set up identity once again. In .NET 6 there is Program.cs class only and not Startup.cs so you probably have to configure all the settings in Program.cs class.

Kindly check [How to Setup and Configure ASP.NET Core Identity](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-setup/) which will help you in this.

Comment: Not completely correct. In .NET 6 you can still use startup.cs or optionally only program.cs you aren't forced to remove the startup.cs file.

Comment: Additionally the OP wrote _it's still in .NET Core 2.2_ you can still run that in VS 22.